# REFERENCES keyword in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, keyword

I was hoping someone could explain to me the purpose of the SQL keyword REFERENCES

```
CREATE TABLE wizards(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT,
  age INTEGER
, color TEXT);

CREATE TABLE powers(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name STRING,
  damage INTEGER,
  wizard_id INTEGER REFERENCES wizards(id)
);
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to look this up and I initially thought that it would constrain the type of data you can enter into the powers table (based on whether the wizard_id ) However, I am still able to insert data into both columns without any constraint that I have noticed.

So, is the keyword REFERENCES just for increasing querying speed? What is its true purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It creates a [Foreign Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to the other table.  This can have performance benefits, but foreign keys are mostly about data integrity.  It means that (in your case) the `wizard_id` filed of `powers` must have a value that exists in the `id` field of the `wizards` table.  In other words, powers must refer to a valid wizard.  Many databases also use this information to propagate deletions or other changes, so the tables stay in sync.

Just noticed this.  A reason that you're able to bypass the key constraint may be that foreign keys aren't enabled.  See [Enabling foreign keys](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) in the SQLite3 documentation.

Comment: thanks that is exactly what it is. Didnt know foreign keys constraint by default is turned off.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. REFERENCE alone does not create a foreign key; it only declares that an attribute in-table is functionally equivalent to an attribute in another table. A foreign key is declared using FOREIGN KEY and indicates that a set of attributes in-table refers to another table's primary key; that is, a foreign key can uniquely identify rows in another table. All foreign keys are references, but not all references are foreign keys.

Comment: @NolanStrait the documentation here https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html disagrees with you.  The `REFERENCES` keyword alone is sufficient in sqlite to create the foreign key.

Comment: @IanMcLaird By I admit that I misunderstood, but this remains misleading in that (A) the definition of "foreign key" you are using contradicts the Wikipedia definition of "a set of attributes in a table that refers to the primary key of another table" and (B) you make no distinction between table-level and column-level foreign key constraints. Column-level foreign key constraints do not necessarily conform to the popular definition of foreign key just mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered, there are two main benefits of using `REFERENCES`, and an important distinction to be made between its use with and without `FOREIGN KEY`.

#### It gives the DBMS room to optimize

Without using REFERENCES, SQLite would not know that attribute `id` and attribute `wizard_id` are functionally equivalent. The more known constraints you can define for the Database Management System (SQLite in this case), the more freedom it has to optimize the way it handles your data under the hood.

#### It can enforce or encourage good practice

Reference declaration can also be useful for enforcement and warning provision. For example, say you have two tables, `A` and `B`, and you assume that `A.name` is functionally equivalent to `B.name`, so you attempt a join: `SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.name = B.name`. If REFERENCE was never used to indicate functional equivalency between these two attributes, the DBMS could warn you when you make the join, which would be helpful in the case that these attributes only happen to have the same name but are not actually meant to represent the same thing.

#### `REFERENCES` does not always create a "foreign key"

Contrary to what has already been suggested, references and foreign keys are not the same thing. A **reference** declares functional equivalency between attributes. A **foreign key** refers to the primary key of another table.

EDIT: @IanMcLaird has corrected me: the use of `REFERENCES` does always create a foreign key of some kind, although this conflicts with the popular definition of foreign key as "a set of attributes in a table that refers to the primary key of another table" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)).

**Using `REFERENCES` without `FOREIGN KEY` may create a "column-level foreign key" which operates contrary to the popular definition of "foreign key."**

There is a difference between the following statements.

```
driver_id INT REFERENCES Drivers

driver_id INT REFERENCES Drivers(id)

driver_id INT,
FOREIGN KEY(driver_id) REFERENCES Drivers(id)
```

The first statement assumes that you would like to reference the primary key of `Drivers` since no attribute is specified. The third statement requires that `id` be the primary key of `Drivers`. Both assume you want to make a foreign key by the popular definition provided above; both create a **table-level foreign key**.

The second statement is tricky. If specifying an attribute which is the primary key of `Drivers`, the DBMS may opt to create a table-level foreign key. But the specified attribute does not *have* to be the primary key of `Drivers`, and if it isn't, the DBMS will create a **column-level foreign key**. This is somewhat unintuitive for those who are first approaching databases and learn the less-flexible, popular definition of "foreign key."

Some people may use these three statements as if they are the same, and they may be functionally identical in many general use cases, but they are not the same.

All that said, this is just my understanding. I am not an expert in this subject and would greatly appreciate additions, corrections, and affirmations.

Comment: The `REFERENCES` keyword is used *specifically* to create foreign key constraints.  The target of the reference must uniquely identify a row, though it need not *strictly* be the primary key.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595695/what-is-difference-between-foreign-key-and-reference-key  All uses of the `REFERENCES` keyword are, in fact, foreign keys.

Comment: @IanMcLaird This contradicts the first line of the Wikipedia article for Foreign Key that you linked in your original answer: "A foreign key is a set of attributes in a table that refers to the primary key of another table." This is also the definition I've been taught, but I think I can see why your definition is useful. Do SQLite or other DB management systems have different definitions?

Comment: At the time I wrote my answer in 2013, that first line read "In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that uniquely identifies a row of another table."  The primary key is a specific case of this rule, so loosely, foreign keys generally reference primary keys, but the rule is uniqueness, not the primary key per se.  (At *least* in the case of SQLite and MSSQL, and very likely others).