# SQL Does "REFERENCE" makes the "FOREIGN KEY" automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

When using `REFERENCE` do we also need to use `FOREIGN KEY` and what is the difference between the two.

**For example:**

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

**Versus:**

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

it seems to work without including the keywords "FOREIGN KEY", so I was wondering in w

I feel like this is a really basic question but could not find an answer to it.

Comment: There's a good discussion on the subject here:
[What is difference between foreign key and reference key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595695/what-is-difference-between-foreign-key-and-reference-key)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#foreign-key-constraints) is pretty clear:

> ```
> column_name AS computed_column_expression   
> [ PERSISTED [ NOT NULL ] ]  
> [   
>     [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]  
>     . . .
>     | [ FOREIGN KEY ]   
>         REFERENCES referenced_table_name [ ( ref_column ) ]   
>         [ ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE } ]   
>         [ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION } ]   
>         [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ]   
>
>     | CHECK [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ] ( logical_expression )   
> ]
> ```

For inline foreign key definitions, the `FOREIGN KEY` and `CONSTRAINT` keywords are optional (they are enclosed in square braces).  Hence, the two versions do the same thing.