# syntax differences MySQL / PostgresSQL for foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have used many databases that other people built with foreign keys but have only recently been learning how to include them myself.

Can see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12315244/4288043) that the following two statements with and without 'FOREIGN KEY' are equivalent:

```
author_id INTEGER REFERENCES author(id)

author_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES author(id)
```

Then the following runs perfectly on Postgres but produces an error in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
        city     varchar(80) primary key,
        location point
);

CREATE TABLE weather (
        city      varchar(80) references cities(city),
        temp_lo   int,
        temp_hi   int,
        prcp      real,
        date      date
);
```

(tested here - https://dbfiddle.uk/)

What are the differences in the syntax for this between the two dialects?

Comment: Why not just try both in Postgres and see what happens?

Comment: I only have Postgres installed at the moment.. - suspect they would both work. What do you think?

Comment: You can use a tool like [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) to do the tests (MySQL / PostgreSQL) you need.

Comment: Thanks @wchiquito something is different I think, just edited the question with code which works in one but not the other.

Comment: Have you visited [MySql official documentation?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks, I have been reading that documentation and trying different things with that query above on dbfiddle and still have not gotten it to work. If you like, post a translation of it into MySQL, will keep trying in the mean time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to express a foreign key relationship in a create table statement.  Here are some ways:

Inline with the column definition:

```
city      varchar(80) references cities(city),
```

Explicitly as a foreign key:

```
city      varchar(80),
. . .
foreign key (city) references cities(city),
```

Explicitly as a constraint:

```
city      varchar(80),
. . .
constraint fk_weather_city foreign key (city) references cities(city),
```

MySQL does not support the first version, with inlined constraints.  Most if not all other databases do.

The first version only handles foreign keys with a single column reference, so it is not as general as the other methods (and the syntax allows for naming constraints and for the `foreign key` keyword for the inline foreign key definitions).

The explicit definition is more general (handling multiple columns).  I tend to prefer explicitly named constraints.  I do admit to sometimes using the inline version, simply because it is more convenient.

Comment: ...and best practice is to name the constraint (so the third option)