# Does using REFERENCES without FOREIGN KEY still create a foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have done some SQL before but not loads. I am a bit confused about what REFERENCES does if you use it without FOREIGN KEY when creating your table e.g.

```
author_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
```

As opposed to...

```
FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

If these are different what is the difference? And if they are the same which form should be preferred?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one:

```
author_id INTEGER REFERENCES users,
```

...is a shorthand of:

```
author_id INTEGER REFERENCES users (id),
```

...that is a shorthand of:

```
FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES users (id)
```

...that in turn is a shorthand of the SQL standard:

```
CONSTRAINT <constraint-name> 
FOREIGN KEY (<column>) 
REFERENCES <table>(<columns>)
```

The first one covers the basic, most common case, and is succint. Good.

Now, the full syntax covers the general case with all possible variations. Consider for example:

- **Composite foreign keys**:

  ```
  book_id int not null,
  chapter_id int not null,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (book_id, chapter_id) 
    references chapter (book_id, chapter_id)
  ```

  Since it's a composite key, it cannot be specified at the column level, but at the table level.
- **Forking foreign keys**:

  ```
  owner_id int not null,
  constraint fk2 foreign key (owner_id) references person (id),
  constraint fk3 foreign key (owner_id) references company (id)
  ```

  In this case the same column *points to* multiple tables. Imagine this one combined with composite foreign keys...

In general, you'll see composite keys once in a while, and forking foreign keys very rarely. Most of the time you'll see simple foreign keys, and that's why the shorthand syntax is so useful.

Comment: I'm not sure that all of these statements are equivalent. I believe the use of `REFERENCES` without `FOREIGN KEY` specifies a column-level foreign key which operates contrary to the popular definition of foreign key as "a set of attributes in a table that refers to the primary key of another table" (Wikipedia). In your first example, the DBMS assumes you want to reference the primary key of `users`. In the second example, you could reference any attribute in `users`. In the third example, you *must* reference the primary key of `users`.

Comment: @NolanStrait You are correct. The generalization is correct in the specific order of the answer. The specialization would not be. I just read the Wikipedia article and it's geared towards simplicity. The article describes a foreign key as a set of attributes, but it's actually a constraint that exists *between* two tables and that imposes restrictions of *both* tables (not just one).

Answer (score 2):

If you use only REFERENCES PostgreSQL creates a foreign key:

```
postgres=# create table parent(id int primary key);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# create table child(id int primary key, fk int references parent);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# \d child;
               Table "public.child"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           | not null | 
 fk     | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "child_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "child_fk_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (fk) REFERENCES parent(id)

postgres=#
```

From syntax point of view REFERENCES is used at column level whereas FOREIGN KEY is used at table level.

See [What is difference between foreign key and reference key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595695/what-is-difference-between-foreign-key-and-reference-key)