# What's the difference between foreign key constraint and referencing a column?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, create-table

Let's say that we have two tables, `prac` and `prac2`.

CREATE TABLE statement of `prac`:

```
CREATE TABLE prac (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(44),
    area varchar(44)
);
```

I will be having a column named `sid` in `prac2` which will be a foreign key and the column which it will refer to is `id` in `prac`.

The general way to add foreign key in this case would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE prac2 (
    adm_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    sid int,
    fee_status varchar(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES prac(id)
);
```

I thought of a different way to do this and I executed this query:

```
CREATE TABLE prac2 (
    adm_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    sid int REFERENCES prac(id),
    fee_status varchar(20)
);
```

I thought that the query would give some error but it didn't.

The question is what is the difference between these two queries?

Comment: This question was closed while I was writing my answer, so I posted it as an answer on the linked duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67421485/20860

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between foreign key constraint and referencing a column?

The difference is simple - column referencing is parsed but ignored.

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=83b3d121f6c1af672154f97ab93bdd0f) - when column referencing is used then neither index nor constraint / foreign key are created.